# Indenting a list entry in markdown

Tags: markdown

I am not sure if there is a correct way to do this in markdown. I have some text as below

```
* lorem ipsum dola sit amet a hungry dog--
  * hungry dog;
  * dog hungry;  
both dogs are hungry
```

Rendering looks like this:

> - lorem ipsum dola sit amet a hungry dog--
>
>   - hungry dog;
>   - dog hungry;
>     both dogs are hungry

"both dogs are hungry" is a continuation of the sentence before the sublist. I want that text to be aligned with the word 'lorem' rather than the sublist (currently, it is using a line break to appear below the list). Is this possible?

Comment: What is your expected output? Are you using a processor like Pandoc?

Comment: The question was edited. I am using Hugo which uses Goldmark by default. But Pandoc is also supported via configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the following is the required markdown source if using Pandoc:

```
- lorem ipsum dola sit amet a hungry dog--

  - hungry dog;
  - dog hungry;

  both dogs are hungry
```

There are two spaces before the two dashes as well as the phrase “both dogs are hungry”. The following is the HTML5 output from Pandoc:

> [image: HTML5 output]

And the output's source:

```
<ul>
<li><p>lorem ipsum dola sit amet a hungry dog–</p>
<ul>
<li>hungry dog;</li>
<li>dog hungry;</li>
</ul>
<p>both dogs are hungry</p></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You know, this site runs on markdown. So you can actually just set the markdown as described and the text will render as expected and shown in your pic.

Comment: There will be other lists below the example. I use Hugo which uses Goldmark by default.